# International HTML Link to a Phone Number

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization

I am adding a click-to-call button on the mobile version of a webapp. While this will eventually be wrapped in one of the many (crappy) frameworks that create "native" apps and can use an API for direct access, there still exists a real possibility that this we be used purely from the website on a phone.

Enabling this for US is easy using by leveraging `tel` protocol in an anchor. What I am worried about is our international users (of which there are quite a bit).

Are there any established Javascript or even server-side libraries which aid in creating phone number links that are more localized to work internationally?

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/.

It is the only public library that I know of dealing with this.